# Looping program basic

Tags: python, loops, visual-studio-code

I wanted to ask that how can I make my program loop with basic code, (pls don't recommend cryptic ones) such as if a user types 1 it reruns the program and if they type anything else, the program ends soo please help me in this problem.

Comment: What you need is a recursive function which will call itself when input is 1, otherwise it will exit. Read about recursive functions in Python: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion. Why do you need such a functionality though?

Comment: First READ a book about python, just starting the REPL and expect programming inspiration is not a good begin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

### Iteration

Use an infinite `while True` loop and break out if the user enters `1`

```py
while True:
    inp = input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == '1':
        break
    # some code goes here
```

### Recursion

Create a recursive function which returns if the user enters `1`

```py
def get_input():
    inp = input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == '1':
        return
    # some code goes here
    get_input()

get_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while True` loop and break out of it when a certain condition is met:

```
while True:
    if int(input("Enter a number: ")) == 1: # if user's input is '1'
        break # break out of the infinite loop 
        
    # do repetitive stuff here ...
```